# Поиск блондина с максимальным ростом

Tags: c++, struct

Какие-то ошибки в коде, функция поиска просто выводит последнего человека, внесённого в список, а должна выводить блондина с максимальным ростом. Где ошибки? Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct student {    
        string fam, cvet;
        float rost, ves;
    };

short fMenu ();
void fwriteinfile (char *file_name, student *pstud);
void fvvod (student *pstud);
void fpoisk(student *pstud);
void freadfromfile (char *file_name);

int n = 6;

int main()
{
    short choise;
    int count=0;
    char *fName = "D:\\student3.txt";
    student *stud = new student[n];
     do {
        cout<< "Studentov v spiske - "<< count << "/" << n <<endl; 
        choise = fMenu();
        switch (choise) {
            case 1:
                system("cls");
                fwriteinfile(fName, stud);
                count++;
                _getch();
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 2:
                system("cls");
                freadfromfile(fName);
                _getch();
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 3:
                system("cls");
                fpoisk(stud);
                _getch();
                system("cls");
                break;
            case 0:
                cout << "Do svidaniya!!!" << endl;
                system ("pause");
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Oshibka vvoda!!!" << endl;
                cout << "\n\nPress Enter..." << endl;
                _getch();
                system("cls");
                break;
        }
    } while(choise);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

short fMenu () {
    short ch;
    cout << "|--------------------- MENU ----------------------------------------------|\n";
    cout << "|   [1]  Vvod                                                             |" << endl;
    cout << "|   [2]  Vivod                                                            |" << endl;
    cout << "|   [3]  Poisk                                                            |" << endl;
    cout << "|   [0]  Vihod                                                            |" << endl;
    cout << "|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n";
    cout << "Vash vibor: ";
    cin >> ch;
    return ch;
}

void fvvod (student *pstud) {
    cin.ignore();
    cout <<"Vvedite informaciyu o studentah"<<endl; 
    cout << "Familiya: ";
    getline(cin, pstud->fam);
    cout << "Rost: ";
    cin >> pstud->rost;
    cout << "Ves: ";
    cin >> pstud->ves;
    cout << "Cvet volos: ";
    cin >> pstud->cvet;
    cout<<endl;
}

void fwriteinfile (char *file_name, student *pstud) {
    fvvod(pstud);
    FILE *pfile = fopen(file_name,"ab");
    cout<<" ЦДДДТДДДДДДДДДДДДТДДДДДДТДДДДДТДДДДДДДДДДДДДДД·"<<endl; 
    cout<<" є N є  Familiya  є Rost є Ves є   Cvet volos  є"<<endl; 
    cout<<" ЗДДДЧДДДДДДДДДДДДЧДДДДДДЧДДДДДЧДДДДДДДДДДДДДДД¶"<<endl; 
    cout<<"      є  "  "  є"<<setw(10)<<pstud->fam<<"  є"<<setw(7)<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<< pstud->rost<<"  є"<<setw(7)<<pstud->ves;
    cout<<"  є"<<setw(15)<<pstud->cvet<<"   є"<<endl;
    cout<<" УДДДРДДДДДДДДДДДДРДДДДДДДРДДДДДРДДДДДДДДДДДДДДДЅ"<<endl; 
    system("pause");
    fwrite(pstud, sizeof(student), 1, pfile);
    cout << "Dannie v fail zapisani";
    fclose(pfile);
}

void fpoisk (student *pstud) {
    char s[] = "blondin*"; 
    int r=0;
    bool f=true;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            if (pstud->rost>r)
            {
                r=pstud->rost;
            }
        }

    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    if (s==pstud->cvet && r==pstud->rost); 
    {
        cout<<" Familiya:  "<<pstud->fam<<endl;
        cout<<" Rost:  "<<pstud->rost<<endl;
        cout<<" Ves:  "<<pstud->ves<<endl;
        cout<<" Cvet volos:  "<<pstud->cvet<<endl;
        f=false;
    }
    system("pause");
}

void freadfromfile (char *file_name) {
    student *stud = new student[n]; int i=1;
    FILE *pFile = fopen(file_name,"rb");
    cout << "Informatsiya o studentah: " << endl;

    while(!feof(pFile)){
        fread(stud, sizeof(student), 1, pFile);
        if (!feof(pFile)){
                cout <<i<< ": " << endl;
                cout << "Familiya: " << stud->fam << endl;
                cout << "Rost: " << stud->rost << endl;
                cout << "Ves: " << stud->ves << endl;
                cout << "Cvet volos: "<< stud->cvet<<endl;
                system ("pause");
                i++;
        }
     }

    fclose(pFile);
    delete[] stud;
}
```

Comment: вы в функциях обьявляете переменные, такие как int i и bool f, потом меняете их значения, но они  не статические, поэтому вы их дальше не сможете использовать - они ничего не делают, а после вызова функции уничтожаются. И зачем нужна команда  system("pause"); ?..

Comment: Английский бы вам подучить)

Answer (score 0):

`void fpoisk (student *pstud)`  в функцию нужно передавать размерность массива, на который указывает `pstud`. Функция ничего не знает о вашем намерении обьявлять в `main ()`  размерность в переменной `'n'`. Но вы в функции используете это переменное, компилятор должен ругаться... И вам не нужно обьявлять массив `s`, инициализировать его, а потом сравнивать с `pstud->cvet`, а можно сразу написать   `if (pstud->cvet =="blondin*"  && r==pstud->rost);` Кстати здесь нужно удалить ';' 
  Ну и в принципе много чего запутано у вас. В цикле вы неинкрементируете указатель и постоянно сравниваете с тем же элементом, ну и т. д.